# Access to a machine mistakenly deleted from AD

Tags: authentication, passwords, windows, remote-desktop

I mistakenly deleted a machine (WINDOWS 10) from my company's AD domain, the PC is in the office in Istanbul and I am in Italy, we use a local administrative password generator with expiration so the local password is no longer accessible since the machine is no longer in the domain and we should be able to log in remotely with TeamViewer or RDP, we only reach the login page. From the deleted objects of AD it is not possible to restore. Any solution? there are no known local users

Comment: If a domain user account has logged into this PC recently, then you may be able to login using the cached credentials (if the password has not changed). If any domain Administrators have logged in then you may be able to use their account to rejoin it to the domain.

Comment: Are you positive there isn’t any evidence of the machine attempting to communicate with the DC?  Typically the machine should at least be listed as attempting to be part of the domain